# useEffect dependency list and its best practice to include all used variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

According to the react docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect when using the useEffect dependency array, you are supposed to pass in all the values used inside the effect.

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to deal with functions and what to do when the array values change too often.

I don't know how the hook works behind the scenes, so I'm going to guess here.
Since the variables inside the closure might go stale, that would imply that the function is cached somewhere. But why would you cache the function since its not being called unless the dependencies changed and the function needs to be recreated anyways?

I've made a small test component.

```
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("b", b);
  }, [a]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>App {a}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setA(a + 1);
        }}
      >
        AddA
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setB(b + 1);
        }}
      >
        AddB
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can try it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-m5se8 and it works just fine, with no stale values. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

**Edit**:
After feedback that my question is not entirely clear, adding a more specific question:

When after a page load I click on AddB button and then click on AddA button, value displayed in console is 1. According to the docs, I should get a stale value (0). Why is this not the case?

Comment: Please also include the text of your code here in the question itself.  It's not really about it being best practice or not, it's more about React not knowing that something has actually changed if you don't include it.  If you post your code here, we can help you figure out if there are corner cases you might not have considered.

Comment: The code was in the sandbox link, but I've pasted it into the question too.

Comment: Can you formulate your question more clearly?

Comment: When after a page load I click on AddB button and then click on AddA button, value displayed in console is 1. According to the docs, I should get a stale value (0). Why is this not the case?

Comment: @Ivan the _problem_ is that you had to click on AddA button in the first place. Between the time you click AddB and AddA, the effect references `b` from a stale closure.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's good way to put it, but it appears React team decided to stay on the safe side and always assume if value isn't in dependencies, it is stale? Because as we see in example from OP in some cases, it is not stale, even though not in the dependencies.

Comment: @gmoniava _"Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders."_ This doesn't say "always", it simply says "will", which is absolutely true, even in the example given.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree, I referenced your quote in my answer. But my point was different. In OPs example, in practice b isn't a stale closure when OP prints it, because when a was changed, the effect still captured the latest value of b. So sometimes in practice you won't see a stale closure as in OPs example. But react team seems to always assume it maybe a problem, my question is why do you think they did that? To stay on the safe side?

Comment: @gmoniava change `useEffect(() => { console.log("b", b); }, [a]);` to `useEffect(() => { return () => { console.log("b", b); }; }, [a]);`. Good enough?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah that's probably another scenario together with setInterval from my answer where you will see a stale closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When after a page load I click on AddB button and then click on AddA
> button, value displayed in console is 1. According to the docs, I
> should get a stale value (0). Why is this not the case?

The reason why you don't see stale value in that case is that when you click `AddA` a re-render happens. Inside that new render since value of `a` is different from previous render, the `useEffect` will be scheduled to run after react updates the UI (however the values it will reference will be *from current render* - because the function passed to `useEffect` is re-created each time one of its dependencies change, hence it captures values from that render).

Due to above reasons, that is why you see fresh value of `b`.

But if you had such code

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
       setB(b + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
```

`b` would be a stale closure. Since `useEffect` didn't re-run, `b` always has value from the render it was created in, that is the first render and above code wouldn't work as expected, which you can check yourself.

---

I will add this comment by Patrick Roberts from above because it explains well IMHO what react docs may mean when they say "Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders":

> the problem is that you had to click on AddA button in the first
> place. Between the time you click AddB and AddA, the effect references
> b from a stale closure

Comment: Thanks for the example, I can clearly see why there would be a problem there. So can I assume its ok to list just the dependencies I want to "watch" so the effect gets re-executed, as long as I'm careful with what it does?

Comment: @Ivan Yes but most of the time react team recommends to list all of them because sometimes you think you are OK and will not have stale closure, but you might.